# PHP echo same function twice

Tags: php, function

I need to echo a paging function twice,

```
echo blaetterfunktion($seite,  $wieviele_seiten);

content

echo blaetterfunktion($seite,  $wieviele_seiten);
```

I guess that would burden the server twice?

What can I do to have the server burdened just once and still echo it twice?

Comment: Save the result in a variable and echo the variable twice?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it to a variable:

```
<?php
$variable = blaetterfunktion($seite,  $wieviele_seiten);
echo $variable; 
?>

content

<?php
echo $variable;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the result of the function in a variable:

```
<?php
    $result = blaetterfunktion($seite,  $wieviele_seiten);
    echo $result;
?>
content
<?php
    echo $result;
?>
```